# set up python with htmlunit driver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit

i am trying to set up python with selenium htmlunit driver on ubuntu 18.04.
launching selenium standalone server

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
```

output

```
00:00:46.177 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision:e82be7d358
00:00:46.299 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2020-05-25 00:00:46.366:INFO::main: Logging initialized @483ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
00:00:46.685 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
00:00:46.811 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

then in my code i am trying connect to it like this

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT
)
```

and getting error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "htmlunit",
    "version": null,
    "platform": null
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "htmlunit"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$null$4 (NewSessionPipeline.java:76)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow (Optional.java:290)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$createNewSession$5 (NewSessionPipeline.java:75)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet (Optional.java:267)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.createNewSession (NewSessionPipeline.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession.execute (BeginSession.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0 (WebDriverServlet.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

i've looked across internet and found different variations of setting `desired_capabilities` like
`{'platform': None, 'browserName': 'htmlunit', 'version': None}` or
`desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS`
 and launching selenium server like this `java -cp selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar:htmlunit-driver-2.40.9-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3` but this didnt help and the error is the same.

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from selenium import webdriver

pid=Popen(['java','-cp','.\headless\htmlunit-driver-2.45.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar;.\headless\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar','org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3']).pid
print(pid)

driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT) #WITHJS)
driver.get('https://www.stackoverflow.com/')

print(driver.title)

print(driver.current_url)
```